# How to retrieve instance of NSDictionary when AnnotationCallout is tapped? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

My app uses Yelp API to generate json data which I store into a `NSDictionary`. The user clicks on categories and then a mapview populates pins with information from the Yelp API Client. When the user taps the Annotation callout, I want to display a detail view controller with the contents of the Dictionary of data from the Yelp client. I want that instance of the array of businesses so I can properly display the contents on the Detail View Controller.

Here is my code:

This is my Business Model where I query for businesses:

```
class Resturant: NSObject {
    var name: String!
    var thumbUrl: String!
    var address: String!
    var jsonData: NSData!
    var location: NSDictionary!        // location


    init(dictionary: NSDictionary) {
        name = dictionary["name"] as? String
        thumbUrl = dictionary["thumbUrl"] as? String
        address = dictionary["address"] as? String
        location = dictionary["location"] as? NSDictionary
    }

    class func searchWithQuery(map: MKMapView, query: String, completion: ([Resturant]!, NSError!) -> Void) {
        YelpClient.sharedInstance.searchWithTerm(query,sort: 0, radius: 1069, success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, response: AnyObject!) -> Void in
            let responseInfo = response as! NSDictionary
            resultQueryDictionary = responseInfo
            println(responseInfo)
            let dataArray = responseInfo["businesses"] as! NSArray
            for business in dataArray {
                let obj = business as! NSDictionary
                var yelpBusinessMock: YelpBusiness = YelpBusiness(dictionary: obj)
                var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = yelpBusinessMock.location.coordinate
                annotation.title = yelpBusinessMock.name
                annotation.subtitle = yelpBusinessMock.displayAddress
                map.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }
            }) { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
         println(error)
        }
    }
```

And here is my delegate method `calloutAccessoryViewTapped`

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView!, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl!) {
        if (control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView) {
            let selectedLocation = view.annotation;
            let selectedCoordinate = view.annotation.coordinate;
            var latitude = selectedCoordinate.latitude
            var longitude = selectedCoordinate.longitude
            var location:CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
            let businessPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: selectedCoordinate, addressDictionary: nil)
            indicatedMapItem = selectedCoordinate;
            let resturantMock:Resturant = Resturant(dictionary: resultQueryDictionary)
            attractionDict = resturantMock.location;
            performSegueWithIdentifier("attractionToDetail", sender: self);
        }
    }
```

Here is the link to my repo: https://github.com/ssharif6/Park-N-Go

Again, this is the structure of my Yelp Data:

There is an array holding the different NSDictionaries of Business. I want to retrieve the correct instance of the Dictionary when the callout accessory view is tapped.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MKAnnotation` is a protocol. You can create any custom object you want that conforms to that protocol. I would suggest ditching the `MKPointAnnotation` object and creating a custom object that conforms to the `MKAnnotation` protocol, and either stores your dictionary of information or has properties for all the values you need. Then when the user taps on an annotation view the annotation object contains all the information you need.

Alternately you could create a custom subclass of `MKPointAnnotation` that contains an integer index into your array of data.

### Edit:

In your code, you have the following:

```
var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
```

Instead of doing that, create a custom class that conforms to the MKAnnoation protocol:

```
class MyAnnotation: MKAnnotation
{
  //Define the coordinate title (and optionally subtitle) 
  //properties from MKAnnotation protocol

  var annotationDictionary: Dictionary
}
```

Then

```
var annotation = MyAnnotation()
```

Set the coordinate, title, and subtitle just like you're doing, and also set the dictionary property with the data you need. Then add the MyAnnotation object to the map just like you are doing now.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but how would you recommend storing the Dictionary Info into the proper annotation?

Comment: I just edited my answer to provide a clearer explanation of what to do.